# es.playsound Failed to Load Sound

Tags: python

Trying to load a simple sound results in the error: fails to load sound. I have another script setup the same exact way but does not work. What is going on?  I have given the entire (simple) script below.

```
# Eventscripts Imports
import es, playerlib

def load():
    print 'You have loaded Chicken Sh1t'

def unload():
    print 'You have un loaded Chicken Sh1t'

def download():
  es.stringtable('downloadables', 'sound/mysounds/chicken.wav')

def player_say(ev):
    alive_ts = es.getlivingplayercount(2)
    alive_cts = es.getlivingplayercount(3)
    if ev['text'] == 'chicken':
        if alive_ts == 1:
            if alive_cts == 0:
                useridlist = es.getUseridList()
                for usrid in useridlist:
                    es.playsound(ev['userid'], 'sound/mysounds/chicken.wav', 1)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should add some debugging print to know if playsound is ever being called.